# How can I populate a textarea from a URL?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to write a script in PHP that can send a message to some user on a forum. So for example, the message form can be formatted like such:

```
<input>Username Goes Here</input

<textarea>Message Goes Here</textarea>
```

Luckily I am able to populate the input field from how the URL is formatted. However, I am not so lucky with the textarea part.

How would I be able to populate the textarea field?

The link is formatted as such:

```
https://live.xbox.com/en-US/Messages?gamertag=gamertag
```

Where "gamertag" is the recipient

The textarea is formatted as:

```
<textarea class="compose empty" empty="true">Say something here...</textarea>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What value you want to set in textarea?

Comment: What exactly is the output? Just Text or a formatted site? For the last case, you can use a iframe.

Comment: My output will be text, like such: "Your Verification Code is [Insert Code]"

Comment: If you are passing the value through url, then u can use it by obtaining the value using GET/REQUEST methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this :

```
<textarea class="compose empty" empty="true"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['gamertag']);?></textarea>
```

Considering the url is

```
https://live.xbox.com/en-US/Messages?gamertag=gamertag
```

You can get the value of gamertag like :

```
$gamertag = htmlspecialchars($_GET['gamertag']);
$gamertag = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['gamertag']);
```

To include static content :

```
<textarea class="compose empty" empty="true">Your Verification Code is : <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['gamertag']);?></textarea>
```

Comment: Please add `htmlspecialchars` to that – otherwise you are implementing a wonderful XSS vulnerability.

Comment: I don't think you are understanding what I am trying to do. I am trying to use Xbox Live as a verification for my website. So my website will send a user on Xbox Live a code

Comment: @user3116492 : So basically you are trying to by-pass the system?

Answer (score 0):

Your website can't cause a user's browser to pre-populate arbitrary fields on a third party site.

Presumably Microsoft provide a mechanism to pre-populate the username field for the purposes of "Contact me" links, but not the message since the positive use cases for that are far fewer and it encourages spammy messages.

Comment: I thought it was possible to do this using curl to post the data

Comment: No. You can use cURL to post the data *instead of using the form* to post the data. (This will mean the request will come from your server and not the browser, so the cookies will be different, so the logged in user will probably be different). You can't use cURL to populate the form.

Comment: I managed to create a function using cUrl. The problem I am having is the textarea has no "name" or "id." How should I post the data?

Comment: I have $postData = "&Name=". $message; but I'm not sure what to replace 'Name' with since there is no name / id for the textarea

Comment: Reverse engineer the site's JavaScript (or sniff the HTTP request made when you submit the form using the site)